# Downsampling image using Texture Memory

Tags: arrays, cuda, textures

I need to downsample an image.Some reading suggested me that if I use texture memory then this function comes on free and is faster(I am looking for a bilinear interpolation).Could some one tell me how exactly to write the kernel for this ?Here is what I have currently :
(I use (1,1) thread blocks)

```
__global__ void texturekernel( int * final_red){
     int f = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
     int c = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;
     int id=blockIdx.x+256*blockIdx.y;//256 is the width of downsampled image ..original was 512
     final_red[id]=tex2D( refTexture,c+0.5f,f+0.5f);//This is just for the red channel
     //where reftexture is defined as texture <float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> refTexture;

  };
```

This version currently gives me all 0's in the output.

Edited (In this version I am trying to downsample 2 2000*512 size images into 2 1000*256):

```
  texture <float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> refTexture; // global variable !
    cudaArray* myArray; 
    cudaChannelFormatDesc description = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    cudaError rs=cudaMallocArray (   &myArray,&description, 512,2000*2);//



//This line below is part of loop where input image is read row by row ..rowchecker keeps track of the row    

cudaMemcpyToArray(myArray,0,rowchecker++,array_temp_red,sizeof(int)*test_columns,cudaMemcpHostToDevice);

     refTexture.normalized=false;
     refTexture.addressMode[0]=cudaAddressModeClamp;
     refTexture.addressMode[1]=cudaAddressModeClamp;
     refTexture.filterMode=cudaFilterModePoint;

     cudaBindTextureToArray( refTexture,myArray);

              dim3 blockSize(1,1);
              int n_blocks_x=256;
              int n_blocks_y=1000*2;
              dim3 gridSize(n_blocks_x,n_blocks_y);
              cudaMalloc((void**)&finalarray,(2000)*(512)*2/4*sizeof(int));
              texturekernel<<<gridSize,blockSize>>>(finalarray );
```

Answer (score 1):

int id=blockIdx.x+256*blockIdx.y;

This statement crosses the limits of your final_red.

Try this:

```
__global__ void texturekernel( int * final_red){

     int f = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
     int c = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

     int id =c/2 * 256 + f/2;

     final_red[id] = tex2D( refTexture,c+0.5f,f+0.5f);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks Jawad.I tried that and I guess problem is not with the final array but with the call tex2d thing. Just to check I tried doing float xx=tex2D(reftexture,f,c) and it gives me some garbage value .I properly bind the values to the array then why does this happen? any clue?

Comment: Can you expose full code, especially binding of the texture memory.

Comment: Try using simple memory instead of array and bind with cudaBindTexture2D, this will help you to visualize it better. I will go through the code and try to figure out the problem.

Comment: Yes... Jawad is right. Do you have a working version with global memory?

Comment: Yes...I do have a working version but that uses a division step .My main aim is to avoid this extra divide step and use the bilinear interpolation that comes free with texture2D.

Comment: @Jawad: I could not get your point in better visualization ? Shouldnt the code work with tex2d too? I mean it may be worth giving a thought to use say c,f or c+0.5f,f+0.5f to get what I need but right now it just gives garbage value for all of them .So i am not sure if changing the memory model would help?